# Trying to run a javascript test through Truffle. Truffle is not able to read the javascript file or I cannot understand the issue here

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, dapps, mocha

I am trying to run `truffle test` to test a javascript file on windows through powershell. The results keep showing a syntax error on the first character of the .js test file after compiling all contracts. I am guessing that truffle is not able to identify that it is a javascript file or might be something else too. I am noob.

Also, I am using ganache as client and also attaching the truffle-config file.
[image]

Here are the snippets of:

i) Test file-
[image]

ii) cli result for `truffle test`
[image]